# Repair Windows EFI system partition from linux live OS

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

As part of my project I am working on a ubuntu based live os that can be used as system rescue disk for linux as well as windows.

Basically it will be used as a rescue disk in case of boot failures.

This is working fine for linux systems.

I want to add the same feature for Windows as well.
The problem is recovering EFI based installations. I am not able to recover the EFI system partition from the linux env. especially the commands like

> bcdboot
>
> bcdedit

will not be working from linux.

Is there a linux replacement for this commands or is there a way of creating the Windows EFI partition from ubuntu.

Or does anyone knows about the files and flags that need to be set in the EFI System partition for the system to boot.

Comment: There are no linux equivalents to bcdboot and bcdedit.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows boot errors, you're best off creating a Windows rescue CD to go along with your Ubuntu disc. There aren't any linux alternatives to the programs you're looking for. WINE won't help you, either, in this case. It [doesn't support](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2011-October/295658.html) the format that the BCD tools store their info in.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I had a similar problem I wanted to remove ubuntu efi entry in efi bootload, so i opened cmd prompt by using windows live installation usb, there using diskpart(`diskpart`) selected my efi{fat32} partition(`list volume`,`select volume x` here volume x is my efi partition), and assigned a drive letter (`assign letter=z:`) opened the directory EFI in drive z: (`z:` , `dir`, `cd EFI`), here delete the unwanted entries. if u deleted the full EFI directory as i did, then u have to rebuild bcd by `bootrec /rebuildbcd` this command should give os installation entries present and asks you a- "yes", "no, "all" options to add it choose yes or all apropriately,  after that exit and go to troubleshoot and do startup repair. this will automatically take you to your windows.